# MySQL throws a syntax error when specifying columns

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have an issue when trying to import a `.csv` file into a table.

As far as I know (and as I've read in the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)), the syntax is something like this:

```
load data infile '/path/to/my/file.csv'
    into table myTable(field1, field2, field3,..., fieldk)
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\n'
    ignore 1 lines;
```

However, MySQL client throws this error:

> `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n'`

I need to specify the column list, because my table has a column that are not present in the file (the `id` column).

I've checked (and rechecked) the syntax, and everything seems OK... So I don't have a clue what could be wrong. I've tried enclosing the field names in backticks (`) but it doesn't work either... Is the field list wrong? Do I need to specify something I'm missing?

**Background info:**

- OS: Debian 7.5 (wheezy), 64-bit
- MySQL version: 5.5.37-0+wheezy1
- All tables are MyISAM

**Attempted solution:**

I could, of course, create a temporary table and drop the "problematic" column. I've tested this solution, and it works:

```
drop table if exists temp_myTable;
create temporary table temp_myTable like myTable;
alter table temp_myTable drop column id;
load data infile '/path/to/my/file.csv'
    into table temp_myTable
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\n'
    ignore 1 lines;
insert into myTable (field1, field2, ... fieldk)
    select field1, field2, ... fieldk
    from temp_myTable;
drop table if exists temp_myTable;
```

However, I think this is quite cumbersome... Why should I write 6 instructions when I should be able to solve it with one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading more carefully the reference manual, I found that the right way to write the column list is **at the end** of the sentence:

```
load data infile '/path/to/my/file.csv'
    into table myTable
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    lines terminated by '\n'
    ignore 1 lines
    (field1, field2, field3,..., fieldk); -- The field list goes here
```

Right now, I'm feeling really dumb... but I put this knowledge here, just in case anyone is facing this same issue.