# Import huge data set csv in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I'm trying to import a huge data set from a csv file ~400MB with 900000 rows. This file has the information of two relational tables. For example:

["primary_key","name","lastname","phone,"work_id","work_name"]

Every row i have to check if the primary key exists for insert or updated if needed, also i need to verify work, because new works can appear in this dataset.

My person table has more colummns that the csv file has, so i can't replace the line with mysqlimport.

Any ideas on how to work with this?

Comment: MySql is really good at fast data inserting - see [BULK INSERT in MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330314/bulk-insert-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please read the documentation for `LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html); it is a good choice for loading data, even very big files. Quoting from [Reference manual: Speed of insert statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html):

> When loading a table from a text file, use `LOAD DATA INFILE`. This is usually 20 times faster than using `INSERT` statements

Assuming that your table as more columns than the `.csv` file, then you'd have to write something like this:

```
load data local infile 'path/to/your/file.csv'
into table yourTable
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines -- if it has column headers
(col1, col2, col3, ...) -- The matching column list goes here
```

See [my own question on the subject and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875304/load-data-infile-error-mysql-throws-a-syntax-error-when-specifying-columns).

Also, if you need faster inserts, you can:

- Ignore foreign key constraints, with `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` before executing `load data`, and/or
- Disable the indexes of the table with `alter table yourTable disable keys;` before executing `load data`, and rebuilding them afterwards with `alter table yourTable enable keys;`

---

***Untested:*** If your `.csv` file has more columns than your table, I think that you can assign the "exceeding" columns in the file to temp variables:

```
load data local infile 'path/to/your/file.csv'
into table yourTable
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines -- if it has column headers
(col1, col2, col3, @dummyVar1, @dummyVar2, col4) -- The '@dummyVarX` variables
                                                 -- are simply place-holders for
                                                 -- columns in the .csv file that
                                                 -- don't match the columns in 
                                                 -- your table
```